# Swift 3: handle custom error with if condition

Tags: error-handling, swift3

I am a bit confused with throwing custom exceptions in Swift 3.

In C++ I can do this to immediately stop the process in the method, throw an error and handle it without proceeding further.

```
void foo()
{
   try
   {
      if (a > b)
      {
         throw MyException();
      }

      DoOtherStaff();
   }
   catch (const MyException& e)
   {
      HandleError();
   }
}
```

I am trying to implement something like this in Swift 3

```
enum MyError : Error
{
   case myError(String)
}

func foo()
{
   do
   {
      if (a > b)
      {
         throw MyError.myError("My error message");
      }

      DoOtherStaff();
   }
   catch
   {
      HandleError();
   }
}
```

But it tells me me that the error is not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive. Is there a way to handle it?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not C++ so stop using capital letters for function names, please! Thanks. :) — Also lose the semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong *a priori* with the code you showed. As a proof, just copy and paste the following into a playground (or into a `class` definition in an actual project):

```
enum MyError : Error {
    case myError(String)
}
let a = 1
let b = 2
func foo() {
    do {
        if a > b {
            throw MyError.myError("My error message")
        }
        doOtherStuff()
    }
    catch {
        handleError()
    }
}
func doOtherStuff() {}
func handleError() {}
```

That compiles and runs fine in the playground (though of course it doesn't *do* anything). Observe that all I did different from the code you gave was to "fill in the blanks", i.e. provide declarations of all the terms you referred to.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have found the error. I was transferring the code and still had `catch (const MyError& e)`. Very stupid of me....